# Does Remote Desktop Connect on Mac Support Multiple Monitors

Tags: macos, multiple-monitors, remote-desktop, vnc

Does anyone know if [Microsoft Remote Desktop Connect](http://www.microsoft.com/mac/products/remote-desktop/default.mspx) supports multiple monitors from a Mac to a Windows machine?

On Windows you can use:

[This forum post](http://www.officeformac.com/ProductForums/RemoteDesktopConnectionClient/290) says you can't but I'm not sure if there was a new version or an alternative version that does support it.

> When running RDC on a windows computer
>   you can add the following to the
>   executible and get access to a second
>   monitor if it exists: /span.
>
> I've added this to the following
>   location on my mac: Remote Desktop
>   Connection.app/Contents/MacOS/Remote
>   Desktop Connection /span.
>
> This doesn't work. Any ideas how to
>   make this work on a Mac?
>
> or is there another type of software
>   that will remote desktop into my
>   windows based PC at work that will
>   span multiple monitors?
>
> > This is not supported.

Answer (score 2):

On the "alternative version" front:

[CoRD](http://cord.sourceforge.net/) apparently doesn't do multiple monitors either, but I suppose they might possibly release support before the MS tool manages to do so.

CoRD is my favourite Windows Remote Desktop client app for the Mac.  It's based on [rdesktop](http://www.rdesktop.org/), which is available through [MacPorts](http://www.macports.org/).  It looks like **rdesktop** can be used across multiple monitors, if you feel like diving into MacPorts.  So that could be one solution.

Answer (score 0):

Nope, still isn't supported.